# Wrong path to playbooks when using ansible_local

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible_local on Windows to provision my Vagrant VM. I have the following setup for Ansible in my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
  ansible.galaxy_role_file = "provisioning/requirements.yml"
end
```

This is copied from [this example](https://servercheck.in/blog/use-vagrant-18s-new-ansiblelocal-provisioner), and the same configuration is also used in [Drupal VM](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm).

My understanding was that this would look for the playbooks in the `provisioning` subfolder of my project. But instead it is looking for this subfolder in the folder where I installed Vagrant `C:\vagrant\provisioning`.

How can I get Vagrant and Ansible to look for the playbooks in the folder where my Vagrantfile is, and not in the installation directory of Vagrant?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue and can't seem to sort it out.

Looks like a patch was merged and a fix should be out in Vagrant version 1.8.2 See https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6740 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change `config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|`  to  `config.vm.provision :ansible_local do |ansible|`